# Cordova takePhoto is not working

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app that will take photos and I'm learning with Cordova. I used this js:

```
var takePhoto = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, { quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.destinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        targetWidth: 1500,
        targetHeight: 1500
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        $('.photoPreview').show();
        var image = document.getElementById('photoSrc');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        photoData = imageData;
        $('#photoMessage').html('');
    }

    function onError(message) {
    }
}
```

Whenever I click the button, it's not working and nothing happens. Same happens with the function I have used to select existing photo:

```
var selectPhoto = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        targetWidth: 1500,
        targetHeight: 1500
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        $('.photoPreview').show();
        var image = document.getElementById('photoSrc');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        photoData = imageData;
        $('#photoMessage').html('');
    }

    function onFail(message) {
    }
}
```

and to add info to that I'm using this

```
$('#selectPhoto').on('click', function() {
    selectPhoto();
});

$('#takePhoto').on('click', function() {
    takePhoto();
});
```

and this HTML

```
 <button id="selectPhoto" class="photo-button">Select Existing Photo</button>
 <button id="takePhoto" class="photo-button">Take New Photo</button>
```

I'm using the latest Cordova 6.4.0, cordova-ios@4.3.1 and latest cordova-plugin-camera from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Please let me know what I should do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're taking the returned imageData and injecting it directly into the DOM as base64 data. That would work fine, if you changed the camera options to return base 64 using DATA_URL as the option. In summary:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, { quality: 30,
    destinationType: Camera.destinationType.DATA_URL,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    targetWidth: 1500,
    targetHeight: 1500
});
```

instead of:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, { quality: 30,
    destinationType: Camera.destinationType.FILE_URI,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    targetWidth: 1500,
    targetHeight: 1500
});
```

**EDIT:** Jaze has uncovered the real reason, that "destinationType" needs to be capitalized. It's easy to miss! See below for the correct solution:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, { quality: 30,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    targetWidth: 1500,
    targetHeight: 1500
});
```

Comment: It was all DATA_URL before, I just followed the FILE_URI based on the latest Cordova documentations. But I tried DATA_URL again and sadly still didn't work. Thanks sir

Comment: Ah ok. Well, now that you've changed it back, your code looks pretty good to me. Can you confirm somehow that the camera success callback is actually firing, and not onFail (or neither)? I assume you've already done this though.

Comment: Did a lot of test in changing the syntax and Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI as in big "i" has worked! for some weird reason lol, played around the capital D or small d in the ".DestinationType" too. Thanks brother, now it's working so far.

Comment: That is very odd! The documentation must be wrong, or it might just be different for iOS. Good catch! I'll edit my answer so others can find that (odd) solution too.

Comment: Actually, I know what it is. DATA_URI is only working because the default is in fact DATA_URL, so since it cannot find DATA_URI it's just defaulting to DATA_URL. The real reason is that you had not capitalized DestinationType, as it is capitalized in the documentation.

Comment: This is so TRUE! Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL is working just perfectly fine and DATA_URI is terribly wrong will just show you luck and catching it but not right. Thanks for correcting me on that one